# T-SQL: Validate nvarchar ASCII characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ascii

Is there a way to know if the content of a nvarchar column contains only some ASCII characters (33 to 127 exactly) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a validation function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[NVarChar_Validate] (
    @@Value [nvarchar](max),
    @@Min [int],
    @@Max [int]
)
RETURNS [bit]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Index [int] SET @Index = 1

    WHILE @Index <= LEN(@@Value) AND UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@@Value, @Index, 1)) BETWEEN @@Min AND @@Max
        SET @Index = @Index + 1

    RETURN CASE WHEN @Index > LEN(@@Value) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
END
GO
```

And then add a check constraint to the table, for example:

```
ALTER TABLE
    [dbo].[TableToControl]
ADD CONSTRAINT
    [CK_NVarChar_Validate]
CHECK (
    [dbo].[NVarChar_Validate]([FieldToControl], 33, 127) = 1
)
```

As a result all fields will be guaranteed to have chars from 33 to 127 only.